# FreeMarker error with Iterable in <#list>

Tags: freemarker

In a FreeMarker template, I pass a variable to `<#list>`:

```
<#list sectorTags as sector>
     <td colspan="${sector.designatedTags!?size}">${sector.name}</td>
<#else>
     <td>No technology sectors defined.</td>
</#list>
```

However that fails:

```
06:25:03,733 SEVERE freemarker.core.NonSequenceOrCollectionException: Expected a sequence or collection, but this has evaluated to an extended_hash+string (com.tinkerpop.frames.structures.FramedVertexIterable wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel):
==> sectorTags  [in template "reports/templates/techReport-punchCard.ftl" at line 105, column 32]
----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list-#else-container  [in template "reports/templates/techReport-punchCard.ftl" at line 105, column 25]
----
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:295)
...
```

What's going on?

(I am covering this issue with a Q&A if someone else ran into that - I haven't found it here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn `Iterable` support on. It's off by default for backward compatibility. You may also should upgrade FreeMarker, as at least in the current version the error message also contains this:

> Tip: The problematic value is a java.lang.Iterable. Using
>   DefaultObjectWrapper(..., iterableSupport=true) as the object_wrapper
>   setting of the FreeMarker configuration should solve this.

Which, when you configure FreeMarker with the Java API looks like something like this:

```
DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder owb = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_26);
owb.setIterableSupport(true);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(owb.build());
```

Comment: For the reference, here's the [Iterable support PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker/commit/f084603d7d9f76ae5bf0536d2ac6af2041a8db5d)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the variable is an `Iterable`. FreeMarker currently can't handle that (i.e. turn an `Iterable` to an `Iterator` or a `Collection`).

The `Iterable` has to be converted to an `Iterator` explicitely:

```
<#list sectorTags.iterator() as sector>
     <td colspan="${sector.designatedTags!.iterator()?size}">${sector.name}</td>
<#else>
     <td>No technology sectors defined.</td>
</#list>
```

The reason why `Iteratable` is not coverted automatically were discussed in Jira issue (which I can't find now). If I remember correctly, it's because there are some types in Java that are [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) but it is not desirable to turn them into `Iterators` automatically.

Comment: Just for the sake of later readers, FreeMarker does support listing `Iterable`-s directly (no need for conversion). It's a configuration issue; see my answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

Example for Spring

in controller

```
model.addAttribute("blogItems", blogItems);
return "main";
```

in template

```
<#list blogItems.iterator() as blogItem>
   ${blogItem.name}
</#list>
```